# Port C's fread(&struct,....) to Python

Tags: python, c, struct, porting

Hey, I'm really struggling with this one. I'am trying to port a small piece of someone else's code to Python and this is what I have:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t Y[LUMA_HEIGHT][LUMA_WIDTH];
  uint8_t Cb[CHROMA_HEIGHT][CHROMA_WIDTH];
  uint8_t Cr[CHROMA_HEIGHT][CHROMA_WIDTH];
} __attribute__((__packed__)) frame_t;

frame_t frame;

 while (! feof(stdin))
  {
    fread(&frame, 1, sizeof(frame), stdin);

    // DO SOME STUFF
  }
```

Later I need to access the data like so: frame.Y[x][y]

So I made a Class 'frame' in Python and inserted the corresponding variables(frame.Y, frame.Cb, frame.Cr).
I have tried to sequentially map the data from Y[0][0] to Cr[MAX][MAX], even printed out the C struct in action but didn't manage to wrap my head around the method used to put the data in there. I've been struggling overnight with this and have to get back to the army tonight, so any immediate help is very welcome and appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @user287669: The proper way to mark a question "solved" on stackoverflow is to accept an answer with the checkmark icon beside it. This will also make you look like a hoopy frood when you ask future questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) python standard module.
From its documentation (emphasys added):

> This module performs conversions
>   between Python values and C structs
>   represented as Python strings. It uses
>   format strings (explained below) as
>   compact descriptions of the lay-out of
>   the C structs and the intended
>   conversion to/from Python values. **This
>   can be used in handling binary data
>   stored in files or from network
>   connections, among other sources**.

Note: as the data you are reading in the end is of a uniform format, you could also use the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array) module and then "restructure" the data in Python, but I think the best way to go is by using struct.

Comment: Thanks, I almost got this working when I noticed a seemingly meaningless bug which distorted all my output. My solution is now the same as I first stated - sequentially writing from Y[0][0] to Cr[MAX][MAX].

Thanks for the help though.